# Python version settings

Tags: python-2.7

I work on Ubuntu with Wingware Python IDE. The version, which we use by our projects is `2.7.X`

This morning I updated the IDE, and it became a version `>3.x.x`

Now I want to install the old version `2.7.3`, after I read TFM and try to define PYTHONPATH, I check my Python version on Ubuntu with the command:

```
python --version
```

and got the answer `2.7.3`. Now I can not understand, why I have version `3.x.x` in Wingware and *how exactly* (the import file is not clear) I can change my version after setting Python manually described [here](https://wingware.com/doc/intro/tutorial-python-path)

Actually: It depends on wingware, because I can execute `Python 2.7.3` in IPython and in console.

EDIT: I solved this problem myself. Here's my solution: 
Following the [manual](https://wingware.com/doc/intro/tutorial-python-path):

1. Use `Python - Executable`
2. Use Interpreter to find right path (in my way it was `/usr/bin/python3.2`)
3. Go in `/usr/bin/`
4. Select right Python version. This path has ALL Python versions, you should just select the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem someself. I post now my solution for other people. 
After [manual][2] using:

1. Use `Python - Executable`
2. Use Interpreter to find right path (in my way it was `/usr/bin/python3.2`)
3. Go in `/usr/bin/`
4. Select right python version. This path has ALL Python version, you should just select the right one